# Adobe Flash player

Tags: 12.04

I installed Adobe flashplugin-installer 11.2.202.378ubuntu0.12.04.1 from the Ubuntu Software Centre in my computer bt still I cannot watch videos online.What could be the issue. Can somebody propose a remedy ?Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

Be more precise when asking questions. I have to assume you use Firefox and "can't watch videos" means you still get "No flash installed" error. Close yor browser. Then open Terminal and do

```
sudo apt-get purge flashplugin-installer
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Read carefully the output - it has to download files from Internet during installation, and if it fails, it installs no flash but reports everything is OK.